# Can anyone tell me why cannot i get a list of cities from google apis?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is the code

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(cities)&language=pt_BR&key=AIzaSyA8FpY17IMXOcKg7Zwzdv2GdTQLR3OnTTk",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

After I executed above I always get this error.

> maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(citi…nTTk&callback=jQuery1111044755223696120083_1455461549950&_=1455461549951:2
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Plug that URL into a new browser tab and you'll see the problem.

Comment: I already tried with https. Anyway I will change the question show the error more specifically.

Comment: That means that you cannot access that URL from the browser. You have to do it from code on your server.

Comment: I did make the request from the server side.

Comment: As Pointy points out, that is because you are using the wrong endpoint. That endpoint does not allow for client-side capture. You have to run a script on your server to get the code. Is there a reason you are not using the [google maps places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) which has the code in place to call the correct api endpoint?

Comment: @HarshikaRanasinghe "from the server" means "from software running on your own web server".  The code you posted is in a `<script>` tag, so that means it's running in a *client*.

Comment: Ok thanks I understood. I will try. Thanks Pointy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The places-webservice (currently) doesn't support JSONP or XDomainRequests.

To request autocomplete-predictions from client-side you must use the [Autocomplete-Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) of the places-library (its a library of the Maps-javascript-API)

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',function() {
  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description));
      document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
    });
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'Vict',types:['(cities)'] }, displaySuggestions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=pt-BR"></script>
<img src="https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/images/powered-by-google-on-white.png"/>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```